# Facing ImportError in conda virtual env for the transformer models that has been git cloned from Huggingface model hub

Tags: python, git, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm quite new to Python and Deep learning.

I want to use the Salesforce/blip-vqa-base models in my jupyter notebook from huggingface.

My directory structure is:

firstproject (main dir)

1. VQA_test_project.ipynb  (ipython notebook)
2. blip-vqa-base           (this folder has been gitcloned from huggingface)

here firstproject is the virtual env.

Now whenever I'm trying to import the transformer from the VQA_test_project.ipynb file in jupyter notebook using the line

'
from transformers import BlipProcessor, BlipForQuestionAnswering
'

I'm getting the error as follows:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'BlipProcessor' from 'transformers' (/home/others/J20230124/miniconda3/envs/first/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/**init**.py)**

Where I'm doing wrong? I presume that something is wrong with my git cloning.
Here the official huggingface transformer [link](https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/blip-vqa-base/tree/main)